# VBA code that counts a certain color of cells; looping (and displaying count) after reaching a second specified color

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a VBA code that will count the number of times a specified color of a cell appears in a range of cells; for example, count all cells in a range with the color yellow.

The following VBA code accomplishes this task:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

I have been trying to add a loop into this code that will loop each time another specified color (for example, purple) appears. Before looping I want the previous value displayed and then the count reset to 0.

When executing the function, the criteria is entered by selection a cell that is the color the function will be looking for and counting. This is also being called from a worksheet.

Does anyone have any tips or solutions to this?

EDIT:

I am trying to create a function that will loop through data that looks like the following:

[The purple represents the ycolor in the code; when the code reads this color I want the count to be displayed and then reset to zero. This is because the purple represents a new data set (note: there are 7,541 purple lines in the spreadsheet, hence why I want to use a looping VBA function rather than counting). The yellow represents the xcolor in the code; when the code reads this color I want the count to begin and add +1 for every yellow cell found between purple cells. With the code running correctly I would want it to display a 6 for the first purple row, and a 2 for the second purple row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgTqb.png)

In all, there are 185,000 rows in the spreadsheet, so the display doesn't need to be located in a specific location, it could just be an array of numbers that I could graph into a histogram to show the range of frequencies.

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range, log_page As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    Dim ycolor As Long

xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
ycolor = log_page.Interior.ColorIndex

For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
        ElseIf datax.Interior.ColorIndex = ycolor Then
            Debug.Print CountCcolor
            CountCcolor = 0
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

In the code the range_data is the comments column, the criteria is chosen by selecting an empty cell containing just the color yellow, and the log_page is also chosen by selecting an empty cell containing just the color purple (the log_page represents where I want the code to print the total, clear the count, then loop).

I have been able to write a function that correctly tallies all of the yellow rows in the entire spreadsheet; however, have been unable to get it to loop and display outputs correctly in accordance with the purple rows.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need a sub procedure rather than a function.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to pass a multi-cell `criteria` range?  Are you calling this from a worksheet, or another VBA procedure?

Comment: One step back - who/what is determining the color of a range? Is it "random", or is there perhaps conditional formatting/some logic to why a cell is a certain color?

Comment: When executing the function, the criteria is entered by selection a cell that is the color the function will be looking for and counting. This is also being called from a worksheet.

Comment: @BruceWayne The color of the range was determined using a filter identifying key words that needed to be "counted"

Comment: What do you mean with "I would want it to display a 6 for the first purple row, and a 2 for the second purple row."

Comment: You probably want to use `.Interior.Color` instead of `.Interior.ColorIndex`

Answer (score 0):

So i modified your code to this and it works just fine.

```
Sub CountCColor(range_data As Range, x As Range, y As Range)
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    Dim ycolor As Long
    Dim CountCColor1 As Integer

xcolor = x.Interior.ColorIndex
ycolor = y.Interior.ColorIndex


For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
        CountCColor1 = CountCColor1 + 1
        ElseIf datax.Interior.ColorIndex = ycolor Then
            Debug.Print CountCColor1
            CountCColor1 = 0
    End If
Next datax
End Sub
```

So i dont really know where you problem is or what you are looking for. But you might want to take a look at this. This would be the range of frequencies you mentioned. I have hardcoded the colors, because im lazy and i dont know why are saving them in an extra cell if there are only two you want to count. But this Macro counts the yellow cells in arr(0,..) and the rows when a purple line occures in arr(1,..). Every Time a purple line is hit, it will increase the index.

```
Sub Test(range_data As Range)
Dim cell As Range
Dim arr() As Integer, i As Integer: i = 0
Dim yFirst
Dim y As Long, p As Long
y = RGB(255, 255, 0)
p = RGB(112, 48, 160)

ReDim Preserve arr(1, 0)

For Each cell In range_data
    If cell.Interior.Color = y Then
        arr(0, i) = arr(0, i) + 1
    ElseIf cell.Interior.Color = p Then
        arr(1, i) = cell.Row
        Debug.Print (arr(0, i) & " " & arr(1, i))
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve arr(1, i)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

So the output would look like this. In Line 1 is a purple cell and there no yellow line before it, then there are 2 yellow line between the purple lines 1 and 41. And so on. You also should consider that if you only print the values when a purple line occures, if the last line is yellow, it wont print it.

[image]